# C# Method Overloading - Why interger method gets called first? Why not double?

Tags: c#, overloading

I am trying to understand a basic thing regarding Method Overloading

If a class has two methods overloaded like below:

```
Add(int a,int b);
```

and

```
Add(double i, double y);
```

And in `Main` method if I call the method like below:

```
Add(2, 3);
```

Then always the method with integer parameters gets called `Add(int a,int b)`

Why didn't it call the other method `Add(double i, double y)`? As double type can also hold values `2, 3` passed from the main method call.

Comment: because `2,3` are integer parameters. Try `Add(2.0,3.0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler would call the method with parameter closer to what you call. If you call add(2,3), both parameters are integer and it would call add(int, int) for you. [For more details, read this tutorial.](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Comment: If you have two methods, i.e. `static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b; static double Add(double a, double b) => a + b;` and pass in an int and double, overload resolution will end on the double parameter method. This works because there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`

Comment: Thank you for the article link. Interesting one to read as it also talks about other cases that I could not thought about during overloading.

Comment: @jdphenix yes you're right I'll edit it. So that case only results in compilation error if the compiler cannot implicitly cast it?

Answer (score 1):

Because 2 and 3 have type `int`, so the overload that has `int` arguments fits ideally. If you want to have overload with `double` arguments called, you have to pass doubles or floats.